# Problem uploading shapefile to GEE

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine

Im trying to upload my city shapefile in to GEE assets, but its always be error message appear :

> Error: Projection exception. Ensure the projection is specified
> correctly and the coordinates are within its valid area. Detailed
> error: Unable to transform edge (762059.046787, 9207577.596492 to
> 762059.046787, 9207577.596492) from GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", DATUM["D_WGS_1984", SPHEROID["WGS_1984", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]],
> PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],
> AXIS["Longitude", EAST], AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]] PLANAR to EPSG:4326.

I'm already try to reproject the shapefile with ArcGIS, but it's still going to be like this. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: The error tells me your coordinates are very big numbers - probably metres - but the coordinate system is lat-long degrees, which should less than 180. Are you only uploading the .shp file, or is it getting the .dbf and .prj parts of the shapefile too? Is the .prj part correct? Can you load it into a desktop GIS and show it in the right place?

Comment: i upload .prj , .shx, .dbf and .shf file, in zip. in the QGIS, It show the right place. but when i upload to gee, that problem comes again